# SPFx isHtmlString: true on dynamic content (lists)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, content-search-web-part

I'm struggling making web parts with lists on it searchable using SPFx.

My static react cards are working just fine based on this solution: [How to make SPFx web part content searchable](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237621/how-to-make-spfx-web-part-content-searchable/237862#237862)

But then for lists is different. I tried adding the list elements `onInit`, and I can make them searchable, but then if the list changes the `CanvasContent1` field will not change so the crawler will not pick the changes on that page's content.

Is it possible to sync the `CanvasContent1` content which the actual content list?.

This is my current `onInit()` block:

```
  public async onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this._environmentMessage = await this._getEnvironmentMessage();

    this._sp = getSP(this.context);
    const spCache = spfi(this._sp).using(Caching({ store: "session" }));

    const response: IResponseItem[] = await spCache.web.lists
    .getByTitle("React List")
    .items.select("Id", "Title", "FileLeafRef", "CustomField")
    .expand()();

    const items: IFile[] = response.map((item: IResponseItem) => {
        return {
          Id: item.Id,
          Title: item.Title || "Unknown",
          CustomField: item.CustomField || "Unknown",
          Name: item.FileLeafRef,
        };
      });

      this.properties.list = items;
      this.properties.searchableList = "React List:" + items.map((item: IFile) => item.Title).join(", ");
      await super.onInit();
  }
```

If I try adding a regular SharePoint list to a page, I can only see the list title.